# Different versions of "I have no question of my grandmother's dedication", which are acceptable?

Tags: sentence-structure

> "I have no question of my grandmother's dedication."
>   "I have no question of whether my grandmother is dedicated."
>   "I do not question my grandmother's dedication."

Which can be used, grammatically?

Comment: Third one. Do you also need a reason?

Comment: And I  was looking forward to answering a non-question. But alas, I find both a question and an (appropriate and correct)  answer.

Comment: Makes you begin to question your role in life.

Comment: Another possibility: "My grandmother's dedication is beyond question."

Comment: @SvenYargs Should it be "beyond questioning" or just "beyond question"?

Comment: @Nagarajan Shanmuganathan: Idiomatically, in English, "beyond question" is like "above suspicion"—we use the simple noun form "question" or "suspicion" in the phrase, instead of the -ing form "questioning" or "suspecting."

Comment: What are you trying to say? Can you give us some more details?

Answer (score 2):

All can be correct grammatically. Whether they are correct, however, depends on the implication.

The first instance implies that your grandmother's dedication my have been questionable by another; but, you do not question her dedication.

The second instance implies that you have no question whether (or not) your grandmother's dedication exists now regardless of what it was previously or what it might be.

The third instance implies that it is not your place to question the dedication of your grandmother whatever her dedication is at any point. It is none of your business.